# Android, Bluetooth, BTLE, GATT reading characteristic fails?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android app i am developing. It's a BTLE app, i have some BTLE tags i need to talk to.

I do all by the book, discover device, GATT connect (subsequent bonding), write/read characteristics... it works.

Now the weird is that it will stop working if i close and open the application two times.

Let's say i have already one tag correctly connected, bonded and working properly.

phone reboot.
Open app the first time -> everything works.
close app, open again -> everything works.
close app again, open -> unable to receive any readCharacteristic from the GATT callbacks.

In the logs, there is NOTHING DIFFERENT from each attempt. I log each call and print return statuses: no difference. Just the readChar callback is never called.

Android is 4.3, same issue on different phones (S3, S4, Note3)
(note: on app shutdown i properly disconnect all the GATT stuff)

Do you have any ideas on what to check? Or is this a known android bug? I have searched, but could not find anything....

Comment: Sadly that is all to typical of my experience although you look to have more consistency than I do so maybe you can debug a bit more.  Its a good idea to search the bug reports on the btle stuff in Android.

Answer (score 2):

The bluetooth stack on Android 4.3(at least) specially for BTLE definitely has quite some issues. I don't know if it's a specific vendor implementation, driver issues, or what else, but it's honestly a nightmare for developers.

This is what i found out does help to improve things:
- disable Wifi
- forcefully enable/disable bluetooth by code (BluetoothAdapter methods enable() and disable())

In fact, cyclying bluetooth on and off when things start getting "unstable" do fix it. This requires the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN capability and might clearly not be desired, since it will briefly shut down ALL you bluetooth conencted gadgets AND will popup some dialogs to the user where he/she can disable the ongoing restart.

Now i am getting more stable results.

Still, shame on Google (or whoever i don't know) for letting such poor software out in the wild.